# click button show this button number div JQUERY JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have buttons witch has the same clasess. i want to when user click second button show second div, but buttons and divs have the same classes. here is my code.

html:

```
 <button class="test">1</button>
 <button class="test">2</button>
 <button class="test">3</button>

 <div class="divs">1</div>
 <div class="divs">2</div>
 <div class="divs">3</div>
```

Comment: add `id` to each html tag.

Comment: And what did you try? We can't write code for you, we help you to solve problems on what you have tried. [However you can start here.](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most suitable way would be to use id's but there is definitely an alternative way.

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  let btnIndex = $(this).index();
  $('.divs').hide();
  $('.divs').eq(btnIndex).show();
})
```